# How do I get the ID item in the database?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, onitemclicklistener

I am new to android development and must take the value of the id in the clicked item database.
Already searched several posts but not found the answer .

Below is my code Listview :

```js
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.seleciona_jogador_act);

        final BancoController bc = new BancoController(this);
        final ArrayList<JogadorEntidade> jogadorEntidade = bc.arrayJogador(this);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvSelecionar);

        final SelecionaAdapter adapter = new SelecionaAdapter(this, R.layout.adapter_seleciona, jogadorEntidade);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(background));
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alertInserirJogador(SelecionaJogadorAct.this);
            }
        });


        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                //I NEED THIS CODE
                
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "ID: " + ", Posicao: " + position;
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();

                //bc.deletaRegistro(id_player);

                Intent intent = getIntent();
                SelecionaJogadorAct.this.finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

My Adapter:

```js
public class SelecionaAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<JogadorEntidade> {

    Context context;
    int layoutID;
    ArrayList<JogadorEntidade> alJogador;

    public SelecionaAdapter(Context context, int layoutID, ArrayList<JogadorEntidade> alJogador){
        super(context, layoutID, alJogador);
        this.context = context;
        this.alJogador = alJogador;
        this.layoutID = layoutID;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View row = convertView;
        PlayerHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutID, parent, false);

            holder = new PlayerHolder();
            holder.txtNome = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtNomeSelecionar);
            holder.txtVitorias = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtVitóriasSelecionar);
            holder.txtDerrotas = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtDerrotasSelecionar);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (PlayerHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        JogadorEntidade jogadorEntidade = alJogador.get(position);
        holder.txtNome.setText(jogadorEntidade.getNome());
        holder.txtVitorias.setText("V: " + jogadorEntidade.vitórias);
        holder.txtDerrotas.setText("D: " + jogadorEntidade.derrotas);
        return row;
    }

    static class PlayerHolder{
        TextView txtNome;
        TextView txtVitorias;
        TextView txtDerrotas;
    }
```

JogadorEntidade:

```js
public class JogadorEntidade {

    public String nome;
    public Integer id_jogador;
    public String vitórias;
    public String derrotas;

    public Integer getId_jogador() {
        return id_jogador;
    }

    public void setId_player(int id_player) {
        this.id_jogador = id_player;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getVitórias() {
        return vitórias;
    }

    public void setVitórias(String vitórias) {
        this.vitórias = vitórias;
    }

    public String getDerrotas() {
        return derrotas;
    }

    public void setDerrotas(String derrotas) {
        this.derrotas = derrotas;
    }

    public JogadorEntidade(String nome, String vitórias, String derrotas){
        super();
        this.nome = nome;
        this.vitórias = vitórias;
        this.derrotas = derrotas;
    }

    public JogadorEntidade(){}
```

```js
public void insereJogador(JogadorEntidade jogadorEntidade) {

        db = banco.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(banco.NOME_JOGADOR, jogadorEntidade.getNome());
        values.put(banco.VITORIAS, jogadorEntidade.getVitórias());
        values.put(banco.DERROTAS, jogadorEntidade.getDerrotas());

        db.insert(CriaBanco.TABELA_JOGADOR, null, values);
        db.close();
    }
    

    public Cursor carregaJogador() {
        Cursor cursor;
        String[] campos = {banco.NOME_JOGADOR, banco.VITORIAS, banco.DERROTAS};
        db = banco.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = db.query(banco.TABELA_JOGADOR, campos, null, null, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        db.close();
        return cursor;
    }
    

    public void deletaRegistro(int id){
        String where = CriaBanco.ID_JOGADOR + "=" + id;
        db = banco.getReadableDatabase();
        db.delete(CriaBanco.TABELA_JOGADOR, where, null);
        db.close();
    }

    public ArrayList<JogadorEntidade> arrayJogador(Context context) {
        ArrayList<JogadorEntidade> al = new ArrayList<JogadorEntidade>();
        BancoController bancoController = new BancoController(context);
        Cursor cursor;
        cursor = bancoController.carregaJogador();

        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                String nome = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(banco.NOME_JOGADOR));
                String vitorias = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(banco.VITORIAS));
                String derrotas = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(banco.DERROTAS));

                JogadorEntidade jogadorEntidade = new JogadorEntidade(nome, vitorias, derrotas);

                al.add(jogadorEntidade);
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    nome = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(banco.NOME_JOGADOR));
                    vitorias = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(banco.VITORIAS));
                    derrotas = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(banco.DERROTAS));
                    jogadorEntidade = new JogadorEntidade(nome, vitorias, derrotas);
                    al.add(jogadorEntidade);
                }
            }
        }
        return al;
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code for your database controller?

Comment: @cricket_007 i'm update my post with database controller, you can help me?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to request the id when making the query (if the id is the one created in the database the column mame is _id or you can use tablename._id or whatever you need):

```
String[] campos = {"_id", banco.NOME_JOGADOR, banco.VITORIAS, banco.DERROTAS};
```

Then you need to add the id to the object when you read the cursor:

```
public ArrayList<JogadorEntidade> arrayJogador(Context context) {
    ArrayList<JogadorEntidade> al = new ArrayList<JogadorEntidade>();
    BancoController bancoController = new BancoController(context);
    Cursor cursor;
    cursor = bancoController.carregaJogador();

    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            String nome = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(banco.NOME_JOGADOR));
            String vitorias = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(banco.VITORIAS));
            String derrotas = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(banco.DERROTAS));
            long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id",0));

            JogadorEntidade jogadorEntidade = new JogadorEntidade(id, nome, vitorias, derrotas);

            al.add(jogadorEntidade);
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                nome = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(banco.NOME_JOGADOR));
                vitorias = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(banco.VITORIAS));
                derrotas = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(banco.DERROTAS));
            long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id",0));
                jogadorEntidade = new JogadorEntidade(id, nome, vitorias, derrotas);
                al.add(jogadorEntidade);
            }
        }
    }
    return al;
}
```

Anyway this is not the way to go in android. You should read all the list and then show it. You should use the viewholder pattern and only load the player when you are going to show it. Also instead of using a list you should move to recyclerviews. Listviews can be consider deprecated at this point. See the tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html